# Can't find variable: _d when running react native app for the first time

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I just created react native app using `react-native init demoone` and started js server using `react-native start` then trying to execute the app with `react-native run-android` 
But i am getting the following error in emulator when it is installed.

can't find variable: _d(`http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:1`)

[image]

Comment: make sure that your device and your bundle are in same network

Comment: yes they both working in same system, as it was emulator and running in the same system

Comment: This has something to do with how babel transformed your jsx. Somehow you should look at the bundled code and see what is referenced for `__d`.

Comment: can you plz explain what bundled code

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem, while trying to set up the react-native env in Win10 and attempting to run Sample Project.

After hours of banging my head and scrolling through site found the solution in [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11568)!

The problem is, when you run `react-native run-android` from the project root folder, it automatically starts a default instance of node-js packager server at the port 8081. For some reason it doesn't let the hot/live/ or even manual reloading work & throws the same non-descriptive error.

Solution is to stop all running instances of the app & to run:

```
    yarn start
    // or
    npm start
```

from the root folder to create your own bundler server manually. Prefer `npm` or `yarn` over `react-native start` (Worked for me)

And then execute

```
    react-native run-android
```

using another cmd window to run the application on the emulator.

So the idea is to create a separate bundler everytime to run the application.

Works like a Charm!

Answer (score 1):

You need run this command to fix it:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

This sets up a reverse proxy between your emulator/device to your port `8081`. Just make sure your emulator and react native bundler(react-native start) are running before you run this command.
Another thing I came across specific to **android emulator**, set your debug server host to `localhost:8081` from Dev settings in your app, otherwise it doesn't connects to remote debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved as I have created new application which is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start react-native with different port such as 8088

```
react-native start --port 8088
```

then

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

stop the project, then `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android`. Will work correctly